# custom post permalink

Tags: custom-post-types, post-type

I want to make single custom post's permalink like this. 
website.com/cat-1/post-title-1

I have done with one way that is if I keep the post type name, then it shows okay as like this: 
website.com/service/cat-1/post-title-1

So there service is the post type name. When I remove the post type name by keeping the cat-1 and post title, then the other post type singe page shows not found.

So I want to make like this:
website.com/cat-1/post-title-1

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

On the WordPress dashboard navigate to tools > permalinks. Then you will see a " Custom Structure" field under common settings. You can use this to create custom permalinks. Here's a link to the [WordPress codex about permalinks](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks). I think what you need to fill in the custom field is this `/service/%category%/%postname%`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but actually, if I place it into the direct custom permalink structure box, then the other default post will be not found, so I wanted to keep the default post fine and again the custom post fine. And the permalink should be like this:
/%category%/%postname%
So there won't be the post type name "service", I don't want to show this.

Comment: Wordpress will change the original link to the new custom post link. If you want you can look into the htaccess file to redirect the old link to the new one incase anyone has it bookmarked. Remove the service if you dont want that in the link